# CORS issue when I push local file to S3 bucket via javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, amazon-s3, cors

I'm trying to upload a local file to an AWS S3 bucket.
I use the fetch api PUT method. The URL is pre-signed by S3.
I am encountering a CORS issue.

I have no problem uploading ~30kb; it happens with a single request.

But if I upload a 2mb file, it requires 2 requests.
The first is preflight with option method and results in `200 OK`.
But the second is the "real" request and it fails. I have set the CORS policy in S3 as `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"`. The response header of the preflight request has `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"`,
but real request doesn't.

My code is simple:

```
let command = new PutObjectCommand({
    Body: "selectedfile",
    Bucket: "my bucket",
    Key: "filename"    
});
let signedurl = await getSignedUrl({
    region:"myregion",
    credentials:{accessKeyId:"mykey",secretAccessKey:"mykey"}}, command, {expiresIn:3600}
);
let response = await fetch(signedurl, {method: "PUT", body: "selectedfile"});
```

Does anyone have a clue to fix this CORS issue?

Comment: In your CORS config, you also need to explicitly allow the `PUT` method.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use presigned URLs to upload to S3, you need to define a CORS policy on the S3 bucket so that web clients loaded in one domain (e.g. localhost or cloudfront) can interact with resources in the S3 domain. Setting a CORS policy on an S3 bucket is not complicated; however, if you do get it wrong, you can often solve it with the suggestions mentioned in this CORS troubleshooting guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors-troubleshooting.html

I also suggest reading this blog:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/deep-dive-into-cors-configs-on-aws-s3-how-to/

Comment: thanks your answer  <br/>
I already set the CORS policy in my S3,  <br/>
but the "put" is fail even if "option" is ok.